# How to find closed form solution for this non-smooth convex problem?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, optimization, regularization

I have function 
\begin{equation}
f(W)=\lambda ||W||_1 + \gamma \sum_{j} ||wj||_2 + \frac{1}{2} |||W-u||_F^2 
\end{equation}
$u \in R^{m\times T}$, $W \in R^{m\times T}$ and $W_i \in R^T$ is the $i th$row of $W$.

I would like to solve this function w.r.t $W$. If everything was differentiable, I would take derivative w.r.t W and solve the respective equation with w.r.t $W$. since it's not the case,
I write down the optimality condition for following problem as follow and every things get complicated. Would someone help me to write-down optimality w.r.t $W$:

\begin{equation}
0 \in \partial_W (\lambda ||W||_1 + \gamma \sum_{j} ||wj||_2 + \frac{1}{2} |||W-u||_F^2 )
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
=\partial(\lambda ||W||_1) + \partial(\gamma \sum_{j} ||Wj||_2) + (W-u)
\end{equation}

and 
Sub differential of euclidean norm $f(x)=||x||_2$:

\begin{gather*}
\partial f(x)=
    \begin{cases}
\big\{ \frac{x}{||x||_2} \big\} & \text{if } x \neq0\  \\   \big\{ g          \text{ s.t } ||g||_2 \leq 1 \big\} &\text{if } x=0   \end{cases}
\end{gather*}
And 
\begin{gather*}
\partial ||W||_1=
    \begin{cases}
\big\{ \frac{w}{||w||_2} \big\} & \text{if } w \neq0\  \\   \big\{ g          \text{ s.t } ||g||_2 \leq 1 \big\} &\text{if } w=0   \end{cases}
\end{gather*}

Comment: have you tried simulated annealing or genetic algorithm ?  They are great for non convex and non differentiable problems.

Comment: No, this optimization problem is inside of an iteration of an algorithm and in each iteration I need to solve this. I'm looking for closed formula solution for this.